# How can I create this bar with a circle?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a style using CSS and HTML.

My style is like this:

[image: button with a rectangle on the right and an overlaying circle on the left]

I tried it and this is my HTML :

```
<div class="download-content">
  <div class="download-item">
    <div class="download-file">
      <div class="front-number">1</div>
        <p><a href="">Financial Ratio Analysis</a></p>
        <small><span>2013-01-12</span><span>Format | Power Point</span></small>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS :

```
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file {
    background: #027bc6;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.download-content > .download-item > .download-file > .front-number {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
}
```

It was so close to my expected result. But not 100%.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/qiwasegu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My two cents:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/jBx76

**HTML**

```
<div class="files">
    <a href="#">
        <div>
            <div class="name">Financial Ratio Analysis</div>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="date">2014-08-25</div>
                <div class="format">Word</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div>
            <div class="name">Financial Ratio AnalysisFinancial Ratio Analysis (this name is so so so long long long long long long)</div>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="date">2014-08-25</div>
                <div class="format">PDF</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.files {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    counter-reset: file;
}

div.files a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 62px;
    text-decoration: none;
    counter-increment: file;
}

div.files a:before {
    content: counter(file);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 72px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.files div {
    line-height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.files a > div {
    padding: 14px 14px 14px 28px;
    background-color: #017BC6;
}

div.files .name {
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}

div.files .meta {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #bebfba;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.files .meta:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

div.files .date {
    float: left;
}

div.files .format {
    float: right;
}

div.files .format:before {
    content: "Format | ";
}
```

**Hover**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/jBx76/4/

```
div.files a > div,
div.files a:before {
    transition: background-color 350ms;
}

div.files a:hover > div {
    background-color: #000;
}

div.files a:hover::before {
    background-color: #017BC6;
}
```

**Better browser support**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/jBx76/5/

Comment: Clean solution.. how to change hover bg color? In this case I need to set to black when hover on content div (blue color div) and also need to change to blue of the bulet circle...

Comment: DONE!, Check it out (btw, mine handles very long file names and adds the number and the format word).

Comment: Great... How about browser support?

Comment: Forget about transitions in MSIE < 10 (http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) and the hover change on the pseudo element needs a workaround for some browsers (not sure about the :: support), you will need a background image to solve the border-radius on MSIE < 9 (http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) and well, some vendor prefixes in general.

Comment: Anyway, the main thing (the layout) has a good support and even the counter is a good idea (http://caniuse.com/#search=counter). You can replace the animations using a js polyfill and the border-radius using a circle background image (I don't like gradients, sorry).

Answer (score 6):

Here's my shot at a solution. You need to move `.front-number` outside `.download-file` for it to work, though.

```
<div class="download-content">
    <div class="download-item">
        <div class="front-number">1</div>
        <div class="download-file">
            <p><a href="">Financial Ratio Analysis</a></p>
            <small><span>2013-01-12</span><span>Format | Power Point</span></small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.download-content > .download-item {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px
}
.download-content > .download-item > * {
    position: absolute;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .front-number {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file {
    background: #027bc6;
    width: calc(100% - 110px);
    height: 78px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 45px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file  p,
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file  p {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file  small {
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: block;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file  small span:first-child {
  float:left;
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file  small span:last-child {
  float:right;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pelok/1/edit)

Comment: I am using `less` CSS and confusing how to declare this rule there... `.download-content > .download-item > * {
    position: absolute;
}`

Comment: LESS should be backwards compatible with regular CSS.

Comment: @user3733831 LESS is just a way of making css shorter.  It compiles to css.  So.. just put the above in a file and include it on your page, like you do any css file.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the bar with circle effect by using a [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) also (like in below snippet).

Radial gradients work on almost all latest browsers. You can see the full browser support chart [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

```css
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  background: #027bc6;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, transparent 60px, #027bc6 60px);
}
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file > .front-number {
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.download-file p a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
span.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix free library to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="download-content">
  <div class="download-item">
    <div class="download-file">
      <div class="front-number">1</div>
      <p><a href="">Financial Ratio Analysis</a></p>
      <small><span class='left'>2013-01-12</span><span class='right'>Format | Power Point</span></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In the snippet, I have also done the following changes to make the output match the image in question:

- Added `line-height: 70px;` (equal to the circle height) to vertically center the number
- Made the following HTML and CSS changes to position and style your `p` and `small` contents.

**HTML:**

```
<span class='left'>2013-01-12</span><span class='right'>Format | Power Point</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.download-file p a{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
span{
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.left{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
span.right{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With CSS and HTML not exact like as image given is seems to be achievable, but here i given one solution hope it will helps you.

```
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file {
    background: #027bc6;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:48px 0px 0px 48px;
}

.download-content > .download-item > .download-file > .front-number {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    line-height:68px;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HP3f/2/)

Comment: add `margin: -2px;` to front number

Answer (score 2):

I can offer you a "classical" approach with float and static position, divs, CSS, margins etc. In order to get the blue shape precisely, you could also use SVG or a combination of divs with CSS radiuses etc.

http://jsbin.com/cuvitixa/3/edit

What have I done:

1) I separated the background into an additional div and the content you've had before. The div is blue and is behind the text. As it has a margin-left, its edge is shifted below the circle and so it gets its shape.

```
HTML:
<div class="download-item">
  <div class="download-item-bg">&nbsp;</div>
  ...

CSS:
.download-item-bg {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 56px;
  background: #027bc6;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

2) As the new background box shifts down the content, I've pulled the content up.

```
.download-file {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -80px; /* pull the content over the blue background */
}
```

3) Set `line-height` in order to have the big number vertically in the middle.

```
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file > .front-number {
  ...
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px; /* set the number in the middle */
  ...
```

4) Different details just as an inspiration: Text color etc. Added classes to the spans, link text decoration etc etc:

```
HTML:
<span class="subtext bold">2013-01-12</span>
<span class="subtext pull-right">Format | Power

CSS:
.subtext {
  color: #dddddd;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  float: left;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

...

.download-content > .download-item > .download-file a {
   font-family: verdana; /* Similar :-) */
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
}
```

It's also commented online.

**EDIT:**

Removed a box that was not necessary and added more CSS font decoration in order to imitate as much as possible the original. Added code along with the JS Bin link.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of answers, but here's what I came up with.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/coronovu/1)

CSS:

```
.download-content > .download-item > .download-file {
    background: #027bc6;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}

.download-content > .download-item > .download-file > .front-number {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute; left: -25px; top: -4px;
}

.download-file {
  height: 70px;
}

.download-file p {
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

.download-file > p > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.details {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.left {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="download-content">
   <div class="download-item">
     <div class="download-file">
        <div class="front-number">1</div>
        <p class="title"><a href="">Financial Ratio Analysis</a></p>
        <div class="details left">2013-01-12</div>
       <div class="details">Format | Power Point</div>
     </div> 
   </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a gradient and pseudo element it is possible

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9wEu/3/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.download-file {
    margin: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.download-file > .front-number {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height:70px;
    color:white;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 35px;
    position: relative;
}
.box:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    transform:translateX(-100%);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left center, circle, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, blue 50%, blue);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left center, circle, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, blue 50%, blue);
    background-image: radial-gradient(left center, circle, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, blue 50%, blue);
}
```

Comment: Works for me...in Chrome. Added mox prefix.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/HVqXw/92/)**

html

```
<div class="circ">1</div>
<div class="rect">
    <p class="title">Financial Ratio Analysis</p>
    <p class="left">2013-01-12</p>
    <p class="right">Format | Power Point</p>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    font-family: calibri;
}
.circ {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 72px;
    color: white;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.rect { 
    color: white;
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #00f;
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.rect:before {
    content:"";
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 40px 40px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
p {
    margin:10px 5px 2px 50px;
}
.title {    
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<small><span>2013-01-12</span><span style="float:right;padding-right:10px;"> Format  |  Power Point</span></small>
```